# Getting unexpected results from Spark sql Windows Functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It seems like  Spark sql Window function does not working properly .
I am running a spark job in Hadoop Cluster where a HDFS block size is 128 MB and 
Spark Version 1.5 CDH 5.5

**My requirement:**

**If there are multiple records with same data_rfe_id then take the single record as per maximum seq_id and maxiumum service_id**

I see that in raw data there  are some records with same data_rfe_id and same seq_id so hence, I applied row_number using Window function so that I can filter the records with row_num === 1

But it seems its not working when have huge datasets. I see that same rowNumber is applied .

Why is it happening like this?

Do I need to reshuffle before I apply window function on dataframe?

I am expecting a unique rank number to each data_rfe_id

I want to use Window Function only to achieve this .

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rowNumber
 .....

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- transitional_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- seq_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data_rfe_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- service_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_start_date_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_id: string (nullable = true)


 val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(df("data_rfe_id")).orderBy(df("seq_id").desc,df("service_id").desc)
  val rankDF =df.withColumn("row_num",rowNumber.over(windowFunction))
  rankDF.select("data_rfe_id","seq_id","service_id","row_num").show(200,false)
```

Expected result :

```
 +------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
  |data_rfe_id                         |seq_id           |service_id|row_num|
 +------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695826          |4039       |1     |
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695821          |3356       |2     |
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695802          |1857       |3     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2156       |1     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2103       |2     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2083       |3     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2082       |4     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2076       |5     |
```

Actual Result I got as per above code :

```
 +------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
 |data_rfe_id                          |seq_id           |service_id|row_num|
 +------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695826          |4039       |1     |
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695821          |3356       |1     |
 |9ih67fshs-de11-4f80-a66d-b52a12c14b0e|1695802          |1857       |1     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2156       |1     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2103       |1     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2083       |1     |
 |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2082       |1     |
  |23sds222-9669-429e-a95b-bc984ccf0fb0 |1695541          |2076       |1     |
```

Could someone explain me why I am getting these unexpected results? and How do I resolve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to rank , having seq_id and service_id in desc order. Add rangeBetween with range you need. Rank may work for you. following is snippet of code :

```
val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(df("data_rfe_id")).orderBy(df("seq_id"),df("service_id")).desc().rangeBetween(-MAXNUMBER,MAXNUMBER))
val rankDF =df.withColumn( "rank", rank().over(windowFunction) )
```

As you are using older version of spark don't know it will work or not. There is issue with windowSpec here is [reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11481)

Comment: Whe n I used HiveContext my code worked, but it  throwing another exception for some task_id's alone . The exception is                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:106)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getInt(rows.scala:40)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getInt(rows.scala:220)